# create video conference with flex and red5 server

Tags: apache-flex, red5

How can I create video conference with flex in client side and using red5 media server on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just yesterday I saw this opensource project that runs on Red5... (Better to reinvent the wheel ;))

http://www.bigbluebutton.org/

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You may use a free red5/flex video chat http://www.freedevelopment.net/articles/free-video-chat.html